# Regex macro to remove only lines NOT containing specific content

Tags: regular-expression, macro

Given a word list, I would like to delete all lines that do not have a specific content.

For illustration, In the following list, I would like to delete all lines that do not end in `s`.

```
bird
chairs
dogs
cars
cat
elephant
elephants
```

After running the macro, the new list should be

```
chairs
dogs
cars
elephants
```

Does it matter that I am looking for a single character? If it does, then delete lines not ending in `rs` which would yield the following new list.

```
chairs
cars
```

Comment: Why use a macro when you have `:h :global` and `:h :vglobal` ? Either would work, just depends on which pattern you use. The latter is the easier one for your particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As BLayer mentions, the idiom here is

```
:vglobal/pat/delete
```

Shorthand `:v/pat/d`. `:vglobal` (or `:global!`) acts on lines not matching the pattern, where as `:global`/`:g` acts on lines matching the pattern.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need.